# How to do Huffman encoding of base 3

Tags: huffman-code

I have a problem in my program implement Huffman encoding. 
In base 2, I use a binary tree to store codeword, but I don't know how to deal with base 3.
I'm trying to use a trinary tree, but don't know how to implement it with a trinary, how to add 0,1,2 symbol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know little about the huffman tree but instead to use 0 and 1 to mark the branches in a ternary tree I would use the letters A,B and C for each branches. Then I can traverse the tree for a letter and remember the codeword for example: ABBCA.

Comment: It's a tenary tree and if my answer is good you must accept it.

Comment: I used 0,1,2 to mark each branches and traverse the tree like a binary tree. 
Sorry because my English's so bad :(